# Can I get back desktop Gadgets?

Tags: windows-8, desktop-gadget

There is no option to add desktop Gadgets in Windows 8 desktop view, Can i still get them back, **without** having to use untrusted third party software?

Comment: Gadgets were removed from Windows 8/8.1 as they were a security flaw.

Answer (score 8):

**I Found One, the CPU usage widget.**

1. Open the task manager.
2. Go to performance tab.
3. Right click on left bar. as shown below. Or Double click on there.

[image]

4. Then, Enjoy a better widget than Windows 7 with complete info of CPU, RAM, Disk Usage and Network Usage. Just Loved it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I'd love to see some small summary of what applications/processes are using the resources. But I do love your tip, will be useful until then =)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not without resorting to third party software. Windows Desktop Gadgets has been removed from Windows 8.

http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/5/3138572/windows-8-desktop-gadgets-support

Apparently, **Live Tiles** (on the Start screen) is a replacement for Windows Desktop Gadgets.

Answer (score 3):

[See this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/35505-Windows-Sidebar-Gadgets-for-Windows-8-RTM-ADDED-32bit-Version) if you do not want 3rd party software, it installs the sidebar and gadgets that originally came with W8 Release Preview.

or consider this software for easier installation.

[8GadgetPack](http://8gadgetpack.bplaced.net/) (free)
Adding on to Rakib's answer, there is always 8GadgetPack, which brings back the functionality of the desktop gadgets of Windows 7 to Windows 8 in a nifty little sidebar.  It comes pre-installed with a few common gadgets (along with Microsoft's default) and will give you the option to install more .gadget files.

Visit their homepage [here](http://8gadgetpack.bplaced.net/).

[image: Windows 8 Gadgets]

.

[Also see this](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/35505-Windows-Sidebar-Gadgets-for-Windows-8-RTM-ADDED-32bit-Version) if you do not want 3rd party software

.

Comment: are you able to install GPU Observer or other gadgets that measures GPU temperature/memory/etc? because windows 8 blocked or removed the API that were being used on the ones i tested

Answer (score 1):

The gadgets aren't removed from windows 8.

Here is my screen showing the gadgets:

[image: Obviously]

Perhaps the trick was to [enable](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57540793-285/how-to-add-windows-media-center-to-windows-8-pro-for-free/) [`Media Center`](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57540793-285/how-to-add-windows-media-center-to-windows-8-pro-for-free/), which I have just done today, and don't know if gadgets were available earlier.

EDIT:

yes, they are removed from the later builds. Just read [this](http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/5/3138572/windows-8-desktop-gadgets-support).

Comment: You are running release preview.

Answer (score 0):

[GADGETARIAN adds gadget support on Windows 8 and 10](http://windowslivegadgets.com/gallery/317/enable-sidebar-gadgets-windows-8-metro/) in a few seconds, and it is safe, because it just enables the native (now hidden) Windows OS gadget functions.

Comment: This isn't safe. Gadgets were removed because they had a major security flaw.

Comment: Https://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows/gadgets and HTTPS://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/2719662