# All the Windows Desktop Gadgets are removed in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, desktop-gadget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get back desktop Gadgets?](https://superuser.com/questions/493953/desktop-widgets-in-windows-8)

All the Windows Desktop Gadgets are removed in Windows 8 or we can get the RSS feed or Weather on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why one wants to use them. Still, they are available as a [3rd party app](http://8gadgetpack.bplaced.net/)

Comment: There are reason to use them that's why Windows 8 can get back them instead of discarding!

Comment: @A.Antri - They are vulerable to an known exploit.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no desktop gadgets in Windows 8. The built-in support has been removed in favor of Live tiles on Start screen.

Microsoft has also removed gadget download page from their site. There are only several popular gadgets left (for those with Vista or 7).