# Alternative to Desktop Gadgets in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, desktop-gadget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get back desktop Gadgets?](https://superuser.com/questions/493953/can-i-get-back-desktop-gadgets)

I love desktop gadgets from Windows 7 (calendar, time, CPU usage) and now I am on Windows 8.

I know that those things are removed by Microsoft itself, but can I somehow re-add them?

Or is there something alike that works for me directly from desktop and not from the start menu?

Comment: also this one...http://superuser.com/questions/493953/can-i-get-back-desktop-widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no direct way to get the gadgets back, there are indeed many hacks and workarounds. [Ghack.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/08/26/no-windows-8-desktop-gadgets-try-these-two-tools-to-get-them-back/) has a way to do it

There are actually 3 in the above mentioned link:

- **Windows Sidebar / Gadgets for Windows 8 RTM**
- **Windows 8 Desktop Gadgets**
- **8Gadget Pack**

Also check [addictivetips.com](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/bring-back-desktop-gadgets-in-windows-8/) to get them back.